# Google API for small personal project

Tags: python, google-api, raspberry-pi, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to get access to my google calendar on a raspberry pi. As the raspberry pi doesn't have a screen, I couldn't do the normal OAuth flow which involves opening up a browser window. Also doing OAuth is kind of overkill as it is only for personal use. Does anyone know some simpler way to authenticate? Thanks!

Comment: For example, as a method, how about using service account? https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: It's fairly simple. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention/19766913#19766913

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look!

Answer (score 2):

Google Calendar requires OAuth 2.0 authorization. As per the documentation no other methods are supported.

> Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other
>   authorization protocols are supported. If your application uses Google
>   Sign-In, some aspects of authorization are handled for you.

[About authorization protocols](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth#AboutAuthorization)

Another option is to use a Service Account. However, this requires G Suite. If you have a G Suite domain, you can create a service account and then implement Domain-Wide Authority (delegation).

> If you have a G Suite domain—if you use G Suite, for example—an
>   administrator of the G Suite domain can authorize an application to
>   access user data on behalf of users in the G Suite domain. For
>   example, an application that uses the Google Calendar API to add
>   events to the calendars of all users in a G Suite domain would use a
>   service account to access the Google Calendar API on behalf of users.
>   Authorizing a service account to access data on behalf of users in a
>   domain is sometimes referred to as "delegating domain-wide authority"
>   to a service account.

[Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm wondering if there is some way I could just get the refresh and access token and let the oauth client take care of the refreshing.

Comment: I am not aware of a method.