# How can I enable the Internal option in the OAuth consent screen?

Tags: android, google-api

When I trying to choose the Internal option in the OAuth consent screen it tells me

> Because you're not a G Suite user, you can only make your app
> available to external (general audience) users.

How can I enable this option?

Comment: You can enable it by becoming a GSuite user

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54174058/google-api-for-small-personal-project obviously becoming a gsuite user to access your personal data in a programmatic way in a timely fashion is relatively irritating and requires you to pay 7 dollars a month for the privilege.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way to make an internal app is to create the project from a gsuite domain account.

Login to Google though your gsuite domain email and then go to Google developer console and create a project there.  Then your project / application can be set to internal and used internally within the gsuite domain.

If you do not have a gsuite domain then you can not set your project internal and it is there for must remain external.

External apps will need to go though the google verification process.

Comment: Just to add it here. The project must be under the workspace organization on GCP. If its not you have to migrate it first.

Comment: So if I want to make an internal app for a personal project without having a Google Workspace subscription I'm out of luck?

Comment: you can't.  internal is for your workspace domain.   if you don't have a workspace domain then its for the global Gmail domain and not internal

Answer (score 3):

At the time of writing, one can create a [Google Cloud Identity](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/set-up-cloud-identity-admin).

[image: Screenshot from Google docs]

Assuming you have a domain name that you can control DNS (to confirm ownership), this allows you to create `Internal` apps, without Google having to validate them.

[image]

I have created internal apps for [Home Assistant](https://www.home-assistant.io/)/Google API integration that do not need re-authorising every 30 days. I have yet to pay Google a penny.

For those with knowledge of Microsoft Azure, it's very similar to Azure AD (Entra ID), which you can also create for free.

HTH